# "supervisor" vs. "mentor"

Tags: word-choice, differences

In master's theses it is common to state two people who oversaw or should have overseen the project.

It is common that only one of these engaged himself with the student's work.
At my university these two are the same who decide the final grade of the work.

If only one of them was  regularly supporting you in your work and the other just participates in the grade-finding, does this this justify the use of the word "mentor" and if so, could both be stated "mentors" on paper ?

Or let's put it easier. Would you call these two within your thesis at the site they are just listed  "mentors" or "supervisors" ?

thanks a lot.

Comment: If it was necessary to distinguish the two words - perhaps because you've just been told *"X is your supervisor, and Y is your mentor"*, and you want to know the implications for your future relationships with the two people - you should probably just assume the ***mentor*** will more actively engage with your ongoing education on a regular basis, and the ***supervisor*** will only intervene on a less frequent (and more formal) basis.

Comment: I've only seen this listed as a *committee* and the *[committee] chair* as in:  There were 3 people on my wife's dissertation committee and her *chair* was the one who provided close guidance throughout the effort.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is important to note that the words *mentor* and *supervisor* have quite different meanings. Supervision suggests a level of authority over the subject. A 'mentor' is defined by Oxford Dictionaries as 'an experienced and trusted adviser'.

Comment: @WS2: Of course. But if I were in OP's position, and I only *had* the two people he describes available to cite as "references", things might be a little different. If some organisation's application form *required* two names in a "mentors" box, I'd put them both there. If the box was headed "instructors" I'd still put them both in. But if *both* boxes were present (and only required one entry in each) I'd fill them in as described.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers I realize I wasn't clear. There has to be a page where both are listed under one title. So my question is what to use as a title for both. "Mentors:" or "Supervisors" I would tend towards "supervisors" but I would like to know what is more common in english speaking areas. If anyone cares to put a cognate comment within an answer I would gladly vote up by the way

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not clear where the OP is studying. But I do have relatively recent experience of having submitted a Master's dissertation in the UK. In my case I had a supervisor to whom I reported throughout the duration of my research and who initially assessed the end result, jointly with a colleague in the department. Finally an external examiner from a different university reviewed the work and the mark given. None of these people were described as 'mentors', a word which seems quite out of place in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're fully capable of figuring out the difference between a mentor and a supervisor. In the situation you've described it's definitely more descriptive to refer to one individual as a mentor and the other as supervisor. In application you should follow whatever is conventional within the context of the institution. If the role the 'supervisor' is filling is generally referred to as mentor then that is the name of the role; regardless of how well the word describes the reality.